# C# if statement single line or

Tags: c#

I came upon some code like this:

```
if (update | true)
{
  // ...
}
```

What is the difference between `||` and `|`. When I hover over them, it shows the `||` is from the `readonly struct System.Boolean` whereas `|` show `bool bool.operator |(bool left, bool right)`

In any case, I wanted to make sure that I can just remove this `if(update | true)` statement since having `update || true` will always evaluate to true, unless the single `|` does something else.

Comment: || means or. | is a bitwise operator, but not really sure what it does. if you say update || true that's like saying if update is true or true is true. So yeah its always gunna return true.

Comment: @henhen The code line `if (update | true)` (or `if (update || true)`) might be intentionally left as such in the code to indicate (and document), that "temporary" the `if()` block should always be executed. Maybe in the future this change will be reversed.

Comment: @Progman good old "self- documenting code" ... haha. Whoever did it, should have left a note, telling why they did it and what circumstances call for taking out the override.

Answer (score 3):

The single pipe `|` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) operates as a logical with booleans, but expressions on both sides are evaluated.   It is also used as a [bitwise or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-or-operator-) when used with integral operands.

The double pipe `||` is the [Conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-).   It computes a logical or, and short-circuits if the first value is true so the second isn't evaluated.

```
public static void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine("'|' operator :", 
    EvaluateToTrue("Single") | EvaluateToTrue("Single"));
  Console.WriteLine("'||' operator:", 
    EvaluateToTrue("Double") || EvaluateToTrue("Double"));
}

public static bool EvaluateToTrue(string s) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", s);
  return true;
}
```

See [a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y1PVCX) - 'Single' is output twice
but 'Double' is only output once because `||` short-circuits if the left-hand argument is true.

Comment: This is the right answer